# Will duplicate query results return a reference?

Tags: java, spring

My environment utilizes Spring's repositories, services in addition to Hibernate/JPA.  I'm wondering if I query a user by their ID, but I query them twice via a loop or something, will there be 1 or 2 instances of that user?  Will Spring recognize that it's a user already in memory and simply return a reference to the first one that was queried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a new reference because of *offline transaction isolation*. That means that current user with the same ID might be changed by some other transaction that is taking place at the same time so it is unsafe to provide the same instance.

And you can test that easily. Turn on the debugger and check it.